# Multiple Independent IntegrationFlow

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Is below the correct way to configure multiple independent IntegrationFlows in the same Spring Boot application? Is there any more optimization that could be done?

```
@Bean("flow1")
public IntegrationFlow integrationFlow1() {

    return IntegrationFlows.from(jdbcMessageSource1(), p -> p.poller(pollerSpec1()))
                            .split()
                            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
                            .transform(transformer1, "transform")
                            .enrichHeaders(headerEnricherSpec -> headerEnricherSpec.header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
                            .handle(Http.outboundGateway(url1)
                                        .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                                        .expectedResponseType(String.class)
                                        .requestFactory(requestFactory))
                            .get();
}

@Bean("flow2")
public IntegrationFlow integrationFlow2() {

    return IntegrationFlows.from(jdbcMessageSource2(), p -> p.poller(pollerSpec2()))
                            .split()
                            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
                            .transform(transformer2, "transform")
                            .enrichHeaders(headerEnricherSpec -> headerEnricherSpec.header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
                            .handle(Http.outboundGateway(url2)
                                        .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                                        .expectedResponseType(String.class)
                                        .requestFactory(requestFactory))
                            .get();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have so far is fully OK and legit.

If your flows don't share any common logic, then have the structure similar is expected. On the other hand even if they look similar at the moment, it doesn't mean that their logic (one or both) might not be changed in the future. Of course it is much safer to divide your business logic into separate microservices, but that's not wrong to have several units of work in the same application.

You may need to pay attention that shared `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` in Spring Boot has only one thread by default. So, to support those polling flows in parallel you might increase the pool config: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.task-execution-and-scheduling

Comment: Awesome catch, thank you. I was wondering myself why did not the flows start at the same time and why were they referring to the same thread-name :)

Comment: sorry to ask on a closed discussion but is so related. The `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` configuration applies ONLY for PollerSpec? We see fine with multiple JmsInboundAdapter without scheduling additional threads.

Comment: Mostly yes . The scheduler is also used in aggregator, MQTT message driven channel adapter, for example.

Comment: Thanq, just an observation threads span as per the concurrency set when `DefaultMessaListenerContainer` is used, thereby not requiring to increase the scheduler thread pool count. Hope this is fine.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are asking about JMS in this question. Really not related to the scheduler concern...